# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in android. I tried to build a project from youtube tutorial but in this layout I got some errors and can't solve it. Someone said me problem in my support library But I don't understand what to do.

Here is my library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Here is the **error log**:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.lol.smartwaiter, PID: 6821
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.lol.smartwaiter/com.example.lol.smartwaiter.FoodDetails}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error
> inflating class <unknown> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
> 
> 
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49:
> Error inflating class <unknown> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
> at
> com.example.lol.smartwaiter.FoodDetails.onCreate(FoodDetails.java:35)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)   
> 
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
> at
> com.example.lol.smartwaiter.FoodDetails.onCreate(FoodDetails.java:35) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
> 
> 
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a
> null object reference at
> android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:961)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1007)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:922)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:913)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:94)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:912)
> at
> android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:899)
> at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:16425) at
> android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:16294) at
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001(FloatingActionButton.java:68)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:822)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:69)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:179)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:151)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
> at
> com.example.lol.smartwaiter.FoodDetails.onCreate(FoodDetails.java:35) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)  at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lol.smartwaiter.FoodDetails">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_food"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:title="Food Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                   <LinearLayout
                       android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                       <ImageView
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                       <TextView
                           android:id="@+id/food_price"
                           android:text="1,000"
                           android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                           android:textSize="18sp"
                           android:textStyle="bold"
                           android:layout_weight="9"
                           android:layout_width="0dp"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                   </LinearLayout>

                  <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        app:textSize="8sp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:finalNumber="20"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_description"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: How?
Actually I don't understand it.

Comment: Please add your activity/fragment.

Comment: Try to cleanup your dependency too. You have 2 “compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'”. It’s also better to use an exact version number (e.g. 26.0.1)